# Laravel Backpack save image with original name

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-backpack, mutators

I am using laravel backpack for my backoffice and i need to upload some images, i copy the code from their website and works fine, but i need the original name on the images, i tried some things, but is not working.

What i need to change here?

```
public function setImageAttribute($value)
    {
        $attribute_name = "image1";
        $disk = "uploads"; // or use your own disk, defined in config/filesystems.php
        $destination_path = "productimg"; // path relative to the disk above

        // if the image was erased
        if ($value==null) {
            // delete the image from disk
            \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});

            // set null in the database column
            $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = null;
        }

        // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
        if (starts_with($value, 'data:image'))
        {
            // 0. Make the image
            $image1 = \Image::make($value)->encode('jpg', 90);

        // 1. Generate a filename.
            $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';

        // 2. Store the image on disk.
            \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path.'/'.$filename, $image1->stream());

        // 3. Delete the previous image, if there was one.
            \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});

            // 4. Save the public path to the database
        // but first, remove "public/" from the path, since we're pointing to it from the root folder
        // that way, what gets saved in the database is the user-accesible URL
            $public_destination_path = Str::replaceFirst('uploads/', '', $destination_path);
            $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $public_destination_path.'/'.$filename;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Backpack gets the content of the image file base 64 encoded. So the original file information is discarded.

If you need it, you should use the `upload` field type (but you won't see the image preview) or create your own field type modifying the original (`/vendor/backpack/pro/resources/views/fields/image.blade.php`).

For example you can create a support `<input type="hidden" name="{{ $field['name'] }}__filename">` where you store the file name via JS.

Answer (score -1):

you need to replace this

```
 $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';
```

with this

```
 $filename = $value->getClientOriginalName();
```

but you have to be sure that all your images has an unique name or you must add a random prefix to file name to prevent duplacated names

Comment: `$filename = $value->getClientOriginalName(); // throws exception because $value is base64 image not instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile `